# Construct a List from a series of expressions in Scala

Tags: scala, dsl

When I try to build internal DSLs in Scala, I run into a common problem and I haven't been able to craft a solution.  To make things look a bit more like a typical language, I'd like the syntax to look something like this:

```
model 'Foo {
  decl 'Real 'x;
  decl 'Real 'y;
}
```

In practice, there are several issues.  The first issue is getting a `model` object here to take two arguments in this way.  If anybody has any ideas, let me know.  But what I've done instead is to do something a bit more like this:

```
model('Foo) {
  ...
}
```

Where model is now a function which then returns an object with an `apply` method which then consumes the lambda that follows.  That I can live with.  I could live with a similar issue inside the lambda as well, so things like `decl 'Real 'x` or `decl('Real,'x)` on the inside.  But what I want to do is to get the results of all those expressions inside the squiggly braces to get "returned" as a list.  In other words, what I want is to write something like this:

```
model 'Foo {
  decl('Real,'x);
  decl('Real,'y);
}
```

where `decl(...)` evaluates to something of type `Declaration` and the `{...}` then evaluates to `List[Declaration]`.  I suspect there is some way of using implicits to do this, but I haven't been able to find it.  In short, I'd like to make:

```
model 'Foo {
  decl('Real,'x);
  decl('Real,'y);
}
```

...evaluate to the equivalent of...

```
model 'Foo {
  decl('Real,'x) ::
  decl('Real,'y) ::
  Nil
}
```

Comments or suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a first idea, you could try variable arguments lists, which allows you to use commas instead of semi-colons:

```
case class Declaration(name: String)

def decl( s: String ) = Declaration(s)

case class Model( sym: Symbol, decls: List[Declaration] )

def model( sym: Symbol)( decls: Declaration* ) =
  Model( sym, decls.toList )

val m = model( 'Foo )(
  decl( "bar" ), 
  decl( "baz" ) 
)
```

Alternatively, you could extend a `trait` to get rid of some parentheses and of the commas:

```
case class ModelBuilder( sym: Symbol ) {
  def using( decls: Declarations ) = Model( sym, decls.toList )
}

trait Declarations {

  protected var decls = List[Declaration]()

  protected def decl( s: String ) = 
decls ::= Declaration( s )

  def toList = decls
}

def model( sym: Symbol ) = ModelBuilder( sym )

model( 'Foo ) using new Declarations {
  decl( "bar" )
  decl( "baz" )
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've seen this approach with some of the declarative GUI DSLs as well. I agree that this is close. I was just hoping to not have to introduce () around the whole thing and the need to use "," is problematic because each time you want to add or remove, you need to worry about having ","s between things, but not at the end.

Comment: I modified my answer to answer your comment.

Comment: Ah, very clever. Using constructor syntax and locally defined methods. I like it and I think it could work. In fact, I can simplify it down to "new Model('Foo) { ... }" which prunes the code down. Nice way to exploit the fact that squiggly braces in a constructor context allow you to introduce things easily in that scope.  I wonder if Scala 2.10 macros will make this even simpler?

Comment: Just noticed one problem (when trying to implement). There is no way (I can see) to restrict the calls in the constructor to internally defined definitions. In a sense, it allows statements outside the "grammar" I wish to "enforce". Probably not a big deal in practice.

Comment: It can also be an advantage, for example you can generate declaration programmatically using regular Scala constructs.

Comment: Yes, but I will not capture them unless I invoke one of the built in methods. They will just evaluate as expressions and then get GC'd.

Answer (score 4):

Oh god what have I done?

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

case class Declaration(t: Symbol, name: Symbol)
case class Model(name: Symbol, declarations: List[Declaration])

object model extends Dynamic {
  val buffer = ListBuffer.empty[Model]

  def applyDynamic(name: String)(args: Any*) {
    buffer += Model(Symbol(name), decl.buffer.toList)
    decl.buffer.clear()
  }
}

object decl extends Dynamic {
  val buffer = ListBuffer.empty[Declaration]

  def applyDynamic(t: String)(args: Any*) {
    args match {
      case Seq(name: Symbol) => buffer += Declaration(Symbol(t), name)
    }
  }
}

model Foo {
  decl Real 'x
  decl Real 'y
}

assert(model.buffer.head == Model('Foo, List(
  Declaration('Real, 'x), Declaration('Real, 'y))))
```

Comment: Congrats on a great answer! I guess this is just what `Dynamic` is for.

Answer (score 2):

OK, completely revised this after realising that `'Foo` is supposed to be the model name.

```
trait DSL {

  private var currentModel: ModelBuilder = null
  case class Declaration(kind: Symbol, name: Symbol)
  case class Model(name: Symbol, declarations: List[Declaration])
  case class ModelBuilder(name: Symbol, var declarations: Vector[Declaration]) {
    def -(f: => Unit) = { 
      currentModel = this
      f
      Model(name, declarations.toList)
    }
  }

  def decl (s1: Symbol,  s2: Symbol) {
    currentModel.declarations :+= Declaration(s1, s2)
  }

  object model {
    def - (s: Symbol) = ModelBuilder(s, Vector.empty)
  }
}
```

Then at use-site:

```
object UseSite extends App with DSL {

  val m =

    model - 'Foo - {
      decl ('Real, 'x)
      decl ('Real, 'y)
    }

  println(m)  
    //Model('Foo,List(Declaration('Real,'x), Declaration('Real,'y)))
}
```

So the gimmicks here are

1) using a variable to keep track of the current model

2) using `-` symbols for method names (you could instead use `apply` if you prefer parentheses)

3) using a builder so that the returned class can be immutable

Although, TBH this might be a bit much just to avoid some commas... :)